# Quotient of the hyperbolic plane with respect to commutator group of $\pi_1(\Sigma_g)$

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, gt.geometric-topology, riemann-surfaces, fuchsian-groups, covering-spaces

Let $\Sigma_g$ be a Riemann surface of genus $g\geq 2$ and $G=\pi_1(\Sigma_g)$.
Let $\pi\colon \mathbb{H}\to \Sigma_g$ be the universal covering map. What kind of surface is $\mathbb{H}/[G,G]$?

Moreover, what is $[G,G]$; e.g. if $g=2$?

Comment: The commutator subgroup of a surface group is free. See corollary 4 at http://chiasme.wordpress.com/2014/08/27/on-subgroups-of-surface-groups/ In particular, it can be deduced that $\mathbb{H} / [G,G]$ is not compact from the abelianization of $G$.

Comment: I would run that argument the other way: $\mathbb{H}/[G, G]$ is an infinite covering space of $\Sigma_g$, hence it is noncompact. As a noncompact surface, it's homotopy equivalent to a $1$-dimensional CW complex, hence its fundamental group is free.

Comment: Is there any particular dictionary for surfaces you would like to use, Mohammad?   The surface has fairly direct descriptions in most ways I can think of thinking of surfaces.

Comment: Thanks Seirios: But what is rank of it? Can we say that? at least for g=2?

Comment: Of course it is infinite, but it should be still describe-able in terms on number of ends and genus; e.g. a pair of pants is genus zero with 3 ends. In this case, I feel it should be a genus 0 curve with infinity many ends dictated by the type of free graph.

Comment: I think the following describes the generators:http://mathoverflow.net/questions/38413/commutator-subgroup-of-a-surface-group

Comment: The classification of noncompact boundaryless surfaces is more complicated than that. If orientable, they are classified genus (maybe infinite) and (homeo class of) a pair of compact totally disconnected metrisable spaces of ends $(E\supset F)$, with $F$ the subspace of nonplanar ends. This is due to Kerekjarto (1923). In your case, I would guess that $E$ is a Cantor and $F$ is empty, but this is only a guess.

Comment: It seems I was wrong. Kerekjarto says (if I correctly understood, p. 183 of "Vorlesungen uber Topologie) that this "homology covering" of a genus $g\geq 2$ surface has infinte genus and only one end (so $E=F$=point). So it is homeomorphic to the half-infinite "Jacob ladder".

Comment: @ BS: interesting, I had never heard of such terminologies. Is there any somewhat recent book discussing this sort of things!

Comment: For fun: Finite Jacob ladder can be seen here http://www.cambridgeblog.org/2013/01/into-the-intro-games-and-mathematic/.

Comment: Unfortunately I didn't found any recent textbook on this subject. By the way, the classification theorem proves that the semi-infinite Jacob ladder is homeomorphic to the "Loch Ness monster"! http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loch_Ness_monster_surface

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let me start by interpreting the question "What kind of surface is $S$?" in the case of a general connected oriented topological surface (without boundary). (I am considering only oriented surfaces just for simplicity of discussion.) 
If $S$ had finite complexity, i.e., would be homeomorphic to the interior of a compact oriented surface, you probably would be satisfied by the answer of the type "$S$ is has $n$ ends and genus $g$", since this provides a complete set of topological invariants. Surfaces of infinite complexity are also classified by a certain set of invariants:

1. Its set of ends (regarded as a topological space).
2. Its genus.
3. Its set of ends with positive genus.

You can find more details and references in [this MO post](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/4155/classification-problem-for-non-compact-manifolds).

If you look closely at the surface you are interested in, $H^2/[G,G]$, you realize that its invariants are:

1. The surface is 1-ended (simply because the abelian group $G/[G,G]$ is 1-ended).
2. It has infinite genus (this is easy to see and is explained in Sam's answer).
3. In particular, its only end has positive genus.

To summarize: Your surface is the unique connected oriented topological surface of infinite genus and one end. If you are looking for a different answer, you should clarify what does your question really mean.

Answer (score 7):

$\newcommand{\ZZ}{\mathbb{Z}}\newcommand{\RR}{\mathbb{R}}$Let $S = \Sigma_2$ be the genus two surface.  In this case, $\ZZ^4$ is the deck group of the desired covering.  Consider $\ZZ^4$ inside of $\RR^4$ and add to these points the usual edges labelled $a, b, c, d$ parallel to the four coordinate axes.  This gives a Cayley graph for $\ZZ^4$.

Next, starting at every vertex of the graph we attach a two-cell via the attaching map $abcdABCD$ (capital letters denote inverses).  This is possible because the boundary word describes a closed loop in the graph.  Let $S'$ be the resulting two-complex.  Every edge of $S'$ meets a pair of two-cells while every vertex meets eight two-cells.  The eight corners give the vertex a disk neighborhood in $S'$.

Thus $S'$ is a surface.  Taking the quotient by the action of $\ZZ^4$ gives the original surface $S$.  By the Galois correspondence, $S'$ is the desired covering space.  Note that $S'$ is quasi-isometric to $\ZZ^4$ so it is one-ended.  The loops $abAABa$ and $cdCCDc$, based at the origin, meet in exactly one point.  Thus $S'$ has genus, and so has infinite genus.

This construction works in any genus.  When $g = 1$ the construction produces the universal cover.

Answer (score 2):

Consider the Abel-Jacobi map $\mu : \Sigma_g \to J(\Sigma_g )=\mathbb{C}^g/\Lambda$.
Then take the lift $\widetilde{\mu}: \mathbb{H} \to \mathbb{C}^g$ from the universal covering $\mathbb{H}$ of $\Sigma_g$. It seems to me that the image $X := \widetilde{\mu}(\mathbb{H})$ is the surface $\mathbb{H}/[G,G]$.

Comment: Sure, but this is as abstract as the original definition.

Comment: It tells you something that's not obvious from the original definition: the surface in question is embedded in ${\bf C}^g$ and periodic.  For $g=2$ we even learn that it's the zero-set of $\Theta$.