# Defining a measure of uniformity for measurable subsets of $[0,1]^2$ w.r.t dimension $\alpha\in[0,2]$

Tags: measure-theory, st.statistics, entropy, hausdorff-dimension, hausdorff-measure

Let $(X,d)$ be a metric space. If set $A\subseteq X$, let $H^{\alpha}$ be the $\alpha$-dimensional Hausdorff measure on $A$, where $\alpha\in[0,2]$ and $\text{dim}_{\text{H}}(A)$ is the Hausdorff dimension of set $A$.

**Motivation:** If the set $A\subseteq[0,1]\times[0,1]$, I would like to measure set $A$'s deviation from a uniform subset $A^{\prime}$ of $[0,1]\times[0,1]$ with Hausdorff dimension $\alpha$, where:

> If set $A^{\prime}\subseteq[0,1]\times[0,1]$ has Hausdorff dimension $\alpha$ less than $2$; for all real $x_1,x_2\in J_n$ *where* sequence of sets $(J_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}=(\left\{1/n,2/n,3/n,\cdot\cdot\cdot,1\right\})_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$, if $0\le x_1<x_2\le 1$ and $\mu$ is the [*counting measure*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Counting_measure) *where*:
>
> $$\mu^{\star}(A)=\begin{cases}
> 1/\mu(A) & \mu(A)<+\infty\\
> 0 & \mu(A)=+\infty
> \end{cases}$$
>
> with $\mu^{\star}(A)< x_2-x_1\le 1$; we *get* $A^{\prime}$ is **uniform** in $[0,1]\times[0,1]$, when for $j\in\mathbb{N}$ and $j< n$, the number of squares $[x_1,x_2]\times[x_1,x_2]$ with area $j^2/n^2$ satisfying:
>
> $$H^{\alpha}(([x_1,x_2]\times[x_1,x_2])\cap A^{\prime})=H^{\alpha}(\text{dom}(A^{\prime})){H}^{\alpha}(\text{range}(A^{\prime}))(x_2-x_1)^2$$
> divided by the total # of squares with area $j^2/n^2$ *approaches* $1$ *as* $n,j\to\infty$ and $j/n\to 0$.

Moreover, I want to define a measure of uniformity to be *between* (and including) zero and one (or zero and infinity) such that the larger the measure, the smaller the *non-uniformity*.

**Question:** How do we define such a measure?

Comment: Got straight to the point using [this post](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/a/5697/504799).

Comment: 13 edits is getting ridiculous.  It gives off the vibe that you are using edits to try to keep this on the front page, which is not appropriate.

Comment: @AndyPutman I'll stop. I thought no one is responding because it's unclear. According to the website you can edit as long as there is a good reason to edit.

Comment: There are the general stackexchange rules, and there are also community norms.  MO culture discourages excessive editing, and encourages you to be thoughtful before you post and get it right the first time (so as to not waste people's time).  If you go and browse through well-received questions here, you'll see that they typically have at most one or two edits beyond the initial post.

Comment: It is also the case that not all questions are going to get answers.  This even includes well-received questions; for instance, I asked the following question 13 years ago and still don't know the answer (even though it is decently upvoted): https://mathoverflow.net/questions/38413/commutator-subgroup-of-a-surface-group

Comment: @AndyPutman I know I shouldn’t make edits but note that I don’t like the way the third bullet point of criteria 2. is written. If you say no, I won’t make an edit.

Comment: I really think the constant editing has to stop.  Take this as a lesson for the future: don't post something until you have spent time polishing it into its final form.

Comment: (i) What do you mean by "uniformity for $A$ w.r.t a subset uniform in $[0,1]\times[0,1]$"? In particular, what do you mean by "a subset uniform in $[0,1]\times[0,1]$"? (ii) In "$\alpha<\text{dim}_{\text{H}}(A)$", what is $\alpha$?

Comment: @DavisJohnson : (i) What do you mean by "'almost" all"? What do you mean by "measure has equivalent measures"? (ii) Do you only consider the small squares $[x_1,x_2]\times[x_1,x_2]$ near the diagonal of the unit square or all small squares all over the unit square? (iii) In your response (?) to my previous question (i), you did not even mention "w.r.t a subset uniform in $[0,1]\times[0,1]$". What subset? What do you mean by "a subset uniform in $[0,1]\times[0,1]$"?

Comment: @DavisJohnson : I have really tried to understand your posted question. But my (and your) efforts are not making anything clearer (at least, to me). In your latest response, the long sentence "If $n\ll j$ ..." is not even a sentence, and I cannot parse it even grammatically. In particular, what is "the ratio of all possible rectangles"? I guess I should just give up here.

Comment: @DavisJohnson : This time I can parse your grammar. However, these definitions do not make much sense. In particular, for $\alpha=0$, taking $n=1$, we see that any nonempty subset $A$ of the unit square will be uniform in your sense. For $\alpha=2$, a subset $A$ of the unit square will be uniform in your sense iff its Hausdorff measure is $1$.

Comment: @IosifPinelis I think my definitions make sense now.

Comment: @AndyPutman I know you said no more edits but this one wasn't trivial.

Comment: @DavisJohnson : Your definitions do make a bit more sense now, but they still do not make much sense to me. (i) Does such a set $A'$ as the one described in your post exist? (ii) Why is $A'$ not used at all in your conditions 1, 2, 3, or anywhere in your post? (iii) According to your point 1, if (say) $A$ is a small disk contained in the unit square (say $S$) but you choose(?) for some reason(?) $\alpha$ to be $<2$, then $A$ is maximally uniform in $S$ -- however small the disk $A$ is. In my mind, this does not correspond to any reasonable idea of uniformity.

Comment: Previous comment continued: (iv) Overall, I think the idea of uniformity has hardly anything to do with the Hausdorff dimension (HD). E.g., I think almost everyone would agree that the entire unit square $S$ (of HD $=2$) is maximally uniform (in itself), whereas a fine uniform grid of $n^2$ points (of HD $=0$) in $S$ is approximately uniform in $S$ if $n$ is large. This, again, suggests that the HD has little (if anything) to do with the idea of uniformity.

Comment: @IosifPinelis How would you suggest measuring the uniformity of measurable subsets of  the unit square? Is there a paper on this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is another possible approach, perhaps closer to what the OP had in mind.

Let $S:=[0,1]^2$ be the unit square. "Partition" $S$ naturally into four congruent squares $S_{1,j}$ (with side length $1/2$ each), where  $j=1,\dots,4$; the quotation marks are used here because the $S_{1,j}$'s will have some common boundary points. Next, "partition" each $S_{1,j}$ naturally into four congruent squares (with side length $1/2^2$ each), so that we get $4^2$ squares $S_{2,j}$ for $j=1,\dots,4^2$. Continue doing so, so that at the $k$th step we get $4^k$ squares $S_{k,j}$ for $j=1,\dots,4^k$, for each $k=1,2,\dots$.

Take any subset $A$ of $S$. For each $k=1,2,\dots$ and each $j=1,\dots,4^k$, let
$$A_{k,j}:=(A\cap S_{k,j})-s_{k,j},$$
where $s_{k,j}$ is the southwest vertex of the square $S_{k,j}$, so that $A_{k,j}\subseteq S_k:=2^{-k}S$.

Suppose that for each $k$ we have a "measure" $D_k$ of dissimilarity for subsets of $S_k$, so that for any two subsets $B$ and $C$ of $S_k$ we have a nonnegative real number $D_k(B,C)$, which is the greater the more "dissimilar" $B$ and $C$ are (and is $0$ if $B=C$); here the term "measure" is used in the general sense, not necessarily in the sense of measure theory. For instance, $D_k(B,C)$ may depend on the [Hausdorff distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hausdorff_distance#Definition) between $B$ and $C$ or on some "measure" of the symmetric difference of the sets $B$ and $C$ or on some combination thereof.

Then the distance of the set $A$ from uniformity can be defined by the formula
$$D(A):=\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac1{L^k}\sum_{j=1}^{4^k}\sum_{m=1}^{4^k}
\frac{D_k(A_{k,j},A_{k,m})}{1+D_k(A_{k,j},A_{k,m})},$$
where $L$ is a real number $>16$ (to ensure the convergence of the series). Then $D(A)$ will be small if, for "most" levels $k$ of "zooming", "most" of the intersections of the set $A$ with all the "$k$-level" small squares $S_{k,j}$ "look similar" to one another.
(Of course, $D(A)$ will depend on the choices of $L$ and the dissimilarity "measures" $D_k$.)

For instance, for any $L$ and any $D_k$'s we have $D(S)=0$ -- of course, the unit square $S$ is at distance $0$ from uniformity (in itself).

As another example, for the uniform grid $G_n$ (defined in the [previous answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/449757/36721)) with $n=2^K$ for a natural $K$, any real $L>16$, and any $D_k$'s we have
$$D(G_n)\le \sum_{k=K+1}^\infty\frac1{L^k}\,16^k
=Cn^{-p}\to0$$
as $n=2^K\to\infty$, where $C:=\dfrac{16}{L-16}$ and $p:=\log_2\dfrac L{16}$.
So, we see that $G_n$ is close to uniformity for large $n$, even though the Hausdorff dimension of $G_n$ is $0$ for all $n$ (in big contrast with the Hausdorff dimension of $S$, which is $2$). Thus, again we see that the Hausdorff dimension can hardly have anything to do with the idea of uniformity.

Comment: Do you think such a measure has (a) an application and (b) is worth publishing?

Comment: If so, I might no be able to publish due to my lack of knowledge in the field; however, you might know someone who can.

Comment: @DavisJohnson : I don't think this is worth publishing and, unfortunately, I don't see a good application.

Comment: A person on Reddit wanted to know if it was possible for the measure to differentiate between a “uniform” set and a set with “low discrepancy” from uniformity.

Comment: @DavisJohnson : I am not on Reddit.

Comment: I understand; however, I discussed about the measure on [reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/mathematics/comments/14x2mrx/rewritten_measuring_the_uniformity_of_measurable/jrlcth1/?utm_source=share&utm_medium=ios_app&utm_name=ioscss&utm_content=1&utm_term=1&context=3) and a user wanted to know if the measure differentiates a “uniform” set from a set with “low discrepancy” from uniformity.

Comment: I cannot possibly respond to all users on all social networks. If **you** have an additional question, post it separately. In this case, though, I don't know what a ""uniform" set" could possibly mean, and I don't think it exists at all. I think we can only have sets close to uniformity, but not uniform in any reasonable sense.

Answer (score 1):

Responding to the [latest comment by the OP](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/448614/defining-a-measure-of-uniformity-for-measurable-subsets-of-0-12-w-r-t-dimen?noredirect=1#comment1162181_448614): "How would you suggest measuring the uniformity of measurable subsets of the unit square?" :

1. I think the idea of uniformity has hardly anything to do with the Hausdorff dimension (HD). E.g., I think almost everyone would agree that the entire unit square $S:=[0,1]^2$ (of HD$=2$) is maximally uniform (in itself), whereas a fine uniform grid of $n^2$ points (of HD$=0$) in $S$ is approximately uniform in $S$ if $n$ is large. This, again, suggests that the HD has little (if anything) to do with the idea of uniformity.
2. Moreover, it makes more sense to talk, not about subsets of $S$, but about probability distributions over $S$ being close to uniform -- that is, to the uniform **probability distribution** over $S$. 
   In particular, if $A$ is a finite subset of $S$, we can attach a weight/probability mass $w(x)>0$ to each $x\in A$ so that $\sum_{x\in A}w(x)=1$, and thus we get a probability distribution over $S$ supported on $A$. This way, we can identify any finite subset $A$ of $S$ with the uniform probability distribution supported on $A$.
   This also allows us to consider [multisets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiset) $B$ in $S$, by giving each of the (possibly repeated) elements $x$ of $B$ the weight $w(x)$ proportional to the multiplicity of $x$ in $B$. Also, we can, somewhat similarly, identify a measurable subset $A$ of $S$ of positive Lebesgue measure with the uniform distribution over $A$. Similarly we can do for, say, rectifiable curve images $C\subset S$, to identify $C$ with the uniform distribution over $C$ in the length sense; e.g., we can identify a circle contained in $S$ with the uniform distribution over the circle. Yet more generally, for any subset $M$ of $S$, if we can somehow define the uniform distribution over $M$, we can identify $M$ with that uniform distribution.
3. Anyhow, if $U$ denotes the uniform probability distribution over $S$ and $P$ is any probability distribution over $S$, then we can measure the closeness of $P$ to $U$ by any probability metric (say, by one metrizing the weak convergence of probability distributions over $S$). For instance, we can use the [Wasserstein distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wasserstein_metric#Definition) $W_1(P,U)$ from $P$ to $U$ (based, say, on the Euclidean distance between points of $S$), which is the cost of the optimal transportation of the probability mass distribution $P$ to the uniform probability mass distribution $U$. So, e.g., if $P_n$ is the uniform distribution on the uniform grid $G_n:=\{(\frac in,\frac jn)\colon i=0,\dots,n,\;j=0,\dots,n\}$ in $S$, then $W_1(P_n,U)\asymp\frac1n$, which is small for large $n$ -- that is, the uniform distribution on the uniform grid $G_n$ is close to uniformity if $n$ is large; this seems to make sense. (Recalling that any finite subset $A$ of $S$ can be identified with the uniform probability distribution supported on $A$, we can now also say that the uniform grid $G_n$ itself is close to uniformity if $n$ is large.)

Comment: You are probably correct; however, I hope you can have a look at my post one last time for a definition of uniformity.

Comment: If $\mu(A)=+\infty$, I want $1/\mu(A)=0$ despite being undefined. Does my definition of uniformity make sense?

Comment: @DavisJohnson : I think you have more problems after the latter edit. For one thing, you still some undefined (and possibly nonexistent) "uniform subset $A'$". See my second answer, though.