# Using programming to measure the uniformity of measurable subsets of the unit square?

Tags: measure-theory, st.statistics, approximation-theory, hausdorff-dimension, hausdorff-measure

This is a follow up to [this post](https://mathoverflow.net/q/448614/504799) using [this answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/449772/504799):

Let $S:=[0,1]^2$ be the unit square. "Partition" $S$ naturally into four congruent squares $S_{1,j}$ (with side length $1/2$ each), where  $j=1,\dots,4$; the quotation marks are used here because the $S_{1,j}$'s will have some common boundary points. Next, "partition" each $S_{1,j}$ naturally into four congruent squares (with side length $1/2^2$ each), so that we get $4^2$ squares $S_{2,j}$ for $j=1,\dots,4^2$. Continue doing so, so that at the $k$th step we get $4^k$ squares $S_{k,j}$ for $j=1,\dots,4^k$, for each $k=1,2,\dots$

Take any subset $A$ of $S$. For each $k=1,2,\dots$ and each $j=1,\dots,4^k$, let
$$A_{k,j}:=(A\cap S_{k,j})-s_{k,j},$$
where $s_{k,j}$ is the southwest vertex of the square $S_{k,j}$, so that $A_{k,j}\subseteq S_k:=2^{-k}S$.

If $d_{\text{H}}$ is the [Hausdorff distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hausdorff_distance), then one measure of $A$'s uniformity in $[0,1]^2$ is:

\begin{equation}
D(A):=\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac1{32^k}\sum_{j=1}^{4^k}\sum_{m=1}^{4^k}
\frac{d_{\text{H}}(A_{k,j},A_{k,m})}{1+d_{\text{H}}(A_{k,j},A_{k,m})} \tag{1}\label{1}
\end{equation}

such that the smaller $D(A)$, the smaller $A$'s distance from uniformity; e.g., when $D(A)=0$, $A$ is *uniform* in $[0,1]^2$.

Another measure of uniformity of $A$ can be defined *as* the following:

Let $(X,d)$ is the metric space. Also, if set $A\subseteq X$, let $H^{\alpha}$ be the $\alpha$-dimensional Hausdorff measure on $A$ where $\alpha\in[0,2]$ and $\text{dim}_{\text{H}}(A)$ is the Hausdorff dimension of set $A$.

Then, the other measure of uniformity of $A$ (in $[0,1]^2$) is:

\begin{equation}
D(A):=\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac1{32^k}\sum_{j=1}^{4^k}\sum_{m=1}^{4^k}
\frac{{H}^{\text{dim}_{\text{H}}(A)}(A_{k,j}\, \Delta A_{k,m})}{1+{H}^{\text{dim}_{\text{H}}(A)}(A_{k,j}\, \Delta \, A_{k,m})} \tag{2}\label{2}
\end{equation}

where $\Delta$ is the [symmetric difference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetric_difference) between two sets.

**Question:** Can either $\eqref{1}$ or $\eqref{2}$ be approximated using programming. (I'd prefer Mathematica be used).